# Get users who have modified a file the most using Git

Tags: git

I want to use Git to get the users who have modified a file the most to help me figure out which developer would have most knowledge about it and so would be best able to fix bugs in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash);

```
git log --format=%an | sort -r | uniq -c
```

```
      4 Name-1
    100 Name-2
    192 Name-3
      5 Name-4
      8 root
```

Or; a file specific

```
git log --format=%an -- /tmp/filename.txt | sort -r | uniq -c
```

If you only need the person with the *most* commits; use [`head -1`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html) to only keep that;

```
git log --format=%an | sort -r | uniq -c | head -1
```

---

If you don't have enough data available, you could use the [Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/) or [Github](https://developer.github.com/v3/) API witch will provide a lot more flexibility and data.

Comment: How can I limit that to users who have modified a specific file?

Comment: @ghosttie Most git commands uses this syntax for pointing at certain directories/files: `git log --format=%an -- your/file/here` (i.e. `git ...options... -- filepaths`)

Comment: Just like @chelmertz explained, you can pass a other arg to provide the path.

Comment: To get it sorted with the person who modified the file the most first, I added `| sort -r` to the end - thanks loads!

Comment: Great! I've also included an `head -1` option, to only keep the person with the most modifications

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to edit the top answer, but it is slightly incorrect.

The given answer will give you all of the users who edited the file, and how many commits each made:

```
git log --format=%an | sort -r | uniq -c
```

However, as shown in the answer, these are not sorted by the number of commits. To sort by the number of commits, we need to add in one more call to `sort -r -n`, where the `-n` flag tells sort to sort by a numerical value rather than a lexicographical one (so that 12 is read as bigger than 2):

```
git log --format=%an | sort -r | uniq -c | sort -r -n
```

And finally, if you want to get just the first result (the user with the most commits), you can use `head`, as suggested:

```
git log --format=%an | sort -r | uniq -c | sort -r -n | head -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Code Maat](https://github.com/adamtornhill/code-maat) for this previously, which has a bunch of other nice features.

This is an example output for one of my repos, when using the tool:

```
$ git log --all --numstat --date=short --pretty=format:'--%h--%ad--%aN' --no-renames -- a_file_that_has_many_authors.py > maat2.log
$ java -jar code-maat-1.0.1-standalone.jar -c git2 -l maat2.log -a author-churn
author,added,deleted,commits
Author 1,265,193,24
Author 2,58,15,5
Author 3,262,89,10
Author 4,15,1,2
Author 5,185,401,32
Author 6,714,50,9
Author 7,7,0,1
Author 8,31,9,4
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to do this exclusively from the commandline, but if you're OK with a bit of Python:

```py
import subprocess
from collections import Counter

output = subprocess.run(['git', 'log', '--format=%an', '--', FILENAME], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(Counter(output.stdout.decode().splitlines()))
```